# What does a number in an Undefined control sequence in TeX's prompt do?

Tags: errors, tex-core, interaction

```
$ latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\s666666
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \s
      666666
? 2
<*> \s66
        6666
?
```

In the example above, what did typing a `2` do? Why it picked two characters from undefined control sequence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeX error context lines always comes in pairs. In the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \s
      666666
?
```

the first line (the one that ends with the `\s`) shows you what TeX saw when it found the undefined control sequence: `\s`, so *that* is the control sequence, and not `\s666666` (because numbers usually don't make control sequence names: only letters).

Now about the `2` you typed in: suppose, instead, you had typed `?`, TeX would tell you what to do:

```
phelype@phelype ~> tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
**\s666666
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \s
      666666
? ?
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, 
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
?
```

When you type a number `1` to `9`, TeX will ignore the next `1` to `9` tokens. So when you typed `2`, TeX ignored two of the `6` you had input.  In fact, if I type `2`, as you did, in the prompt above:

```
? 2
<*> \s66
        6666
?
```

TeX will do as promised and ignore the next two tokens (remember that what TeX already processed is in the first line (`\s66`) and the rest in the line below), and wait for input once again.  If I hit `<return>` here, TeX will resume processing the rest of the input (`6666`), and prompt you with `*`, at which point you can type `\bye` and TeX will finish its job and the resulting `.dvi` file will have only `6666` written:

> [image]

Note: I used `tex` in the example to avoid LaTeX's `Missing \begin{document}` error, but the same principle applies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very helpful!

Comment: Hi I have a related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551313/why-there-is-a-text-line-contains-an-invalid-character-after-undefined-contro I'd really appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Thank you always...I have deleted the question on meta.tex.se. Best regards.