# why there is a "Text line contains an invalid character" after "Undefined control sequence" and why "Q" required further input?

Tags: pdftex, tex-core

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-2:pdftex zmx$ latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\s^EH
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \s
      ^^EH
? 1
! Text line contains an invalid character.
<*> \s^^E
         H
? Q
OK, entering \batchmode
```

In the example above, ^E is ctrl+e on MacOS. Obviously it is an invalid character, so that when I typed in "1", it outputted an error message "Text line contains an invalid character".
I then typed in "Q", it seems it didn't start running, but required further input instead.

My question is why it require further input after "Q"?

Actually I'm debugging pdftex for my project.
On pdftex 1.40.18 if you typed in:

\s^EH

1

Q

V

Then there will be a segment fault.
[image]

If anyone is interested in this bug, feel free to discuss with me.

Comment: Doesn't happen with TeX Live 2020 on Linux.  Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: @HenriMenke Just because `^^E` is no longer invalid when LaTeX starts up.

Comment: @egreg Yes, indeed but if I understand the question correctly OP is debugging a document and upgrading should fix it.

Answer (score 18):

0. Original poster: can you please email me at karl at tug.org? You've discovered a bug in the original TeX and DEK will surely want to transfer a hefty balance to you in the Bank of San Seriffe :).
1. the "further input after Q" and "segmentation fault" have the same underlying cause: TeX's data was getting into an inconsistent state in this unusual sequence of interactions.
2. I've committed a fix (thanks to David Fuchs) to TL svn, r55767. It applies to all TeX variants except LuaTeX, which will have to be fixed independently. After a little more testing, I expect Akira will push out new binaries in his w32tex distribution, for anyone who can use that and feels like trying. The TL binaries will not be updated for this.
3. The culprit was that your input caused module 83, <Get user's advice...>, to be invoked when interaction = batchmode. But this is never supposed to happen. Havoc ensues.
4. The "H" (or any text) is needed to cause the crash in web2c because that crash happens due to trying to write the text to a closed \write stream. (selector was decremented from 16, no_print, to 15, which corresponds to \write15. Like I said, havoc.)
5. For the record, I could reproduce the bug by running tex -ini <invalid.in, where invalid.in is a text file containing the four lines:

   ```
   \catcode`\^=7 \catcode`\^^?=15 \s^^?E
   1
   q
   v
   ```

Glad you found it.

Answer (score 8):

As of [TeX version 3.141592653 and Metafont version 2.71828182](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581118/whats-new-in-tex-version-3-141592653), the bug has been fixed. The rest of this answer applies only to previous versions.

---

Note: It just occurred to me that this bug is present in Metafont as well. See the end of this answer.

For the sake of documentation, here’s exactly what makes the bug happen, since
it took me a little while to figure out.

The key players are the two integer variables `selector` and `interaction`.
Let’s focus on `interaction` first, since it’s the simpler of the two. It is
supposed to control whether TeX stops to interact with the user, and it has
four possible values:

- When `interaction` = `error_stop_mode` = 3, TeX stops if an error occurs
  (§82, §530), or if `\pausing` is set to a positive value (§363), or if `\read`
  is used to get input from the terminal (§484), or if `interrupt` is nonzero at
  certain points [after a token list has been scanned (§324), after a line of
  input has been read (§343), and during the processing of ligatures (§753, §911)].
- When `interaction` = `scroll_mode` = 2, TeX does not stop when a nonfatal
  error occurs, unless the problem is that a file can’t be found, in which case
  TeX will still prompt the user for a new file name (§530).
- When `interaction` = `nonstop_mode` = 1, TeX does not stop unless a fatal
  error occurs, or it gets into a situation that requires input from the
  user—namely, if an `\end` command is not present in a file (§360), if a `\read`
  command requests input from the terminal (§484), or if a file cannot be found
  (§530). (These situations are treated as fatal, although they would not be if
  `interaction` is `scroll_mode` or `error_stop_mode`.)
- When `interaction` = `batch_mode` = 0, TeX’s behavior is as when
  `interaction` is `nonstop_mode`, *except that output to the terminal is omitted*
  (§75, §90, §92, §1328). This is important.

Note that the level of user interaction increases as the value of `interaction`
increases. Initially, `interaction` is set to `error_stop_mode` (§74).

The `selector` variable controls where TeX’s various text printing routines
send their output. In TeX82, it has twenty-two possible values, ranging from 0
to 21. When 0 ≤ `selector` ≤ 15, it represents one of the files opened with
`\openout`. The values of `selector` above 15 have the following meanings:

- When `selector` = `no_print` = 16, printing goes nowhere.
- When `selector` = `term_only` = 17, printing goes only to the terminal.
- When `selector` = `log_only` = 18, printing goes only to the transcript file.
- When `selector` = `term_and_log` = 19, printing goes to the terminal and to
  the transcript file.
- When `selector` = `pseudo` = 20, characters are “printed” to a buffer for use
  by the `show_context` procedure, in a process called “pseudoprinting” (§315). This
  setting is not relevant to us.
- When `selector` = `new_string` = 21, characters get appended to the string
  memory (if there’s any space left). This setting is not relevant to us either.

Initially, `selector` is `term_only` (§55, §1332), since no transcript file has
been opened.

The values of `selector` and `interaction` are mostly independent. However, as
you may expect, when `interaction` is `batch_mode`, `selector` should not be
`term_only` or `term_and_log`. In one case, it is set to `term_only`
unconditionally (though temporarily, since the previous value is saved in §534)
in §535, regardless of `interaction`. But the general idea is that
`selector` will be `term_only` or `term_and_log` if and only if `interaction` >
`batch_mode`; in particular, `selector` will be `term_only` or `term_and_log`
when `interaction` = `error_stop_mode`.

When TeX wishes to read a line from the terminal, it calls `term_input`
(usually via `prompt_input`; see §71). This routine makes clever use of the
numeric relation between `selector`’s possible values, in order to echo the
input line if appropriate. The program assumes that `selector` must be either
`term_only` or `term_and_log` upon entry to `term_input` (no other values would
make sense). Hence `term_input` can decrement `selector` and unconditionally
print the line the user input; if `selector` was `term_only`, it becomes
`no_print`, which is correct because the line will have been echoed already
(owing to the nature of terminals), and if `selector` was `term_and_log`, it
becomes `log_only`, which is correct because the line must be written to the
transcript file.

Let’s look at the `error` routine now. Its top level looks like this (§82):

```
procedure error;
  label continue, exit;
  var …;
  begin
    …
    if interaction = error_stop_mode then
      ⟨Get the user’s advice and return⟩;
    …
exit:
  end;
```

And the outline of ⟨Get the user’s advice…⟩ looks like this:

```
loop
  begin continue:
    clear_for_error_prompt;
    prompt_input("? ");
    if last = first then
      return;
    c ← buffer[first]
    if c ≥ "a" then
      c ← c + "A" − "a"; {convert to uppercase}
    ⟨Interpret code c and return if done⟩;
    ⟨Print the menu of available options⟩;
  end
```

The section ⟨Print the menu…⟩ is what it sounds like, except that the option
to type `E` to edit the input file is not listed if no input file is open, and
the option to type a number to delete tokens is not listed if
`deletions_allowed` is false (in order to thwart more than two levels of
recursion in `error`).

The interesting part of ⟨Interpret code `c`…⟩ is a big `case` statement,
switching on the value of `c`. (The uninteresting part is actually ⟨Print
the menu…⟩. I moved it to make the overall flow of the loop clearer.) In the
following descriptions, transfers of control are in **bold**.

1. If `c` is a decimal digit, and if it’s OK to delete tokens, then the number
   of tokens specified by the user are deleted and **control goes to** `continue`.
2. If `c` is `"E"`, then (in TeX82) the user is told what line of what file to
   edit and TeX **terminates**.
3. If `c` is `"H"`, then the help information is printed and **control goes to**
   `continue`.
4. If `c` is `"I"`, then a line of input is read from the terminal as the next
   thing for TeX to process, and **control goes to** `exit` via the `return` macro.
5. If `c` is `"Q"`, then `interaction` becomes `batch_mode`, `selector` gets
   decremented (to suppress terminal output), and **control goes to** `exit`.
6. If `c` is `"R"`, then `interaction` becomes `nonstop_mode` and **control goes
   to** `exit`.
7. If `c` is `"S"`, then `interaction` becomes `scroll_mode` and **control goes
   to** `exit`.
8. If `c` is `"X"`, then `interaction` becomes `scroll_mode` and TeX
   **terminates**.
9. Otherwise, nothing happens; **control falls through** to ⟨Print the menu…⟩
   and we go back to the top of the loop.

There is also a case for `c` = `"D"`, if code for debugging isn’t commented out.
**Control goes to** `continue` afterwards.

[Something interesting to note about cases 5, 6, 7: Each change of
`interaction` is accompanied by a message saying `OK, entering` , followed by
the new mode; e.g., when you type `S`, TeX says
`OK, entering scrollmode`.
Then the program does `print("...")`, so that the message ends up being
`OK, entering scrollmode...`. In case 5, however, `selector` is decremented before
the ellipses, so it ends up going either to the transcript file if `selector`
was `term_and_log` or to nowhere if `selector` was `term_only`; the `...` will not
appear on the terminal. Knuth acknowledges this in the answer to his sixth
exercise for *TeX: The Program* he published in TUGboat (exercises
[here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-2/tb28knut.pdf), answers
[here](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-4/tb30knut-exercises.pdf)).]

The process of deletion is pretty simple. First, the values of certain
global variables (`cur_tok`, `cur_cmd`, `cur_chr`,
and `align_state`) are saved. Then `OK_to_interrupt` is set to false—this
is another measure to stop unwanted recursion, since `error` might be called if
an interrupt occurs and `OK_to_interrupt` is true. Next, `c` is set to the
number typed in by the user. The following loop is executed:

```
while c > 0 do
  begin
    get_token; {one-level recursive call of error is possible}
    decr(c);
  end
```

Hence tokens are deleted by simply reading and ignoring tokens. The `get_token`
procedure can be regarded, for our purposes, as identical to `get_next`. The
recursion can happen because `get_next` might cause `error` to be called. Most
of the erroneous situations that can arise in `get_next` eventually terminate
the program; they are fatal errors. But there’s one direct call to `error`,
which happens when an invalid character is read (§346). The `deletions_allowed`
variable is set to false before the call, and to true afterwards.

So what’s the problem? Let’s consider what happens when you start up plain TeX
and enter the troublesome input. (I'm using plain TeX because `^^?` is already made illegal.) First `\s^^?E` is typed in response to the `**`
prompt. Because the first character of input is `\` (= `escape`), TeX
treats it as regular code (i.e., it doesn’t assume you wanted to `\input` a file
named `\s^^?​E`; see §1337). The `\s` is read and TeX tries to expand a
control sequence named `s`. Since `\s` has no definition, the `expand` routine
calls `error` (§370).

At this point, `interaction` is `error_stop_mode` and `selector` is `term_only`.
(This is why the error has to happen on the first line of input; otherwise the
transcript file is opened and `selector` changes.) The loop in §83 begins. Then
you type `1` (this is case 1 listed above) and §88 starts to be executed, and
`get_next` is called by `get_token`. The invalid character `^^?` (ASCII code 127 = `'177` = `"7F`; see Appendix C of *The TeXbook*) is read and control
moves to §346. The `error` routine is called again.

The values of `interaction` and `selector` have not changed, so the error dialog
is entered as before. Now you type `Q`. The code in §86 runs; `interaction`
becomes `batch_mode`, and `selector` gets decremented to `no_print`. Control
returns from `error` back to `get_next`, which skips over the invalid character
and reads the `E` left in the input. Then we get back to `error`; remember that
we’re in case 1, so control goes up to `continue` and the dialog loop begins
again.

At this point, `interaction` is `batch_mode` and `selector` is `no_print` = 16,
and we are at the top of the loop in §83, *which should be executed **only** if*
`interaction` = `error_stop_mode`. All the pieces of the puzzle are now in
place. The `prompt_input` macro first attempts to print `?` ; nothing is
displayed, because of the value of `selector`. Then `prompt_input` calls
`term_input`, which does `input_ln(term_in, true)`; this is why TeX waits for
input, even though it’s supposed to be in batch mode. The reason there must be
text following the invalid character is that otherwise TeX will encounter the
end of input (in `get_next`, §360) and report a fatal error [`*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)`]. The `fatal_error` procedure (§93) calls
`normalize_selector` (§92), which is intended to avoid situations just like what
I'm describing!

Next `term_input` decrements `selector`; its value becomes 15. If you typed
anything in response to the invisible `?` , then `term_input` will attempt to
print it, by calling `print` on each character in `buffer`, which will end up
calling `print_char`. (Simple exercise: Why can’t `term_input` call `print_char`
directly?) The value of `selector` isn’t one of the six important ones
enumerated above, so `print_char` tries to print to `write_file[selector]`. The
elements of `write_file` are of type `alpha_file`, and none of them are actual
open streams, so what happens now is system-dependent. In Web2C, the result is
that `putc` will be called with a null pointer as its second argument (see
[`fixwrites.c`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/d8f594a02f186c6e3af00c768bf5b309f36f7b1a/texk/web2c/web2c/fixwrites.c)),
which causes a segmentation fault. ∎

---

Now that we know what goes wrong, how might it be fixed? In TeX Live and in the recent tune-up, §83 was
changed to have a test at the start of the loop, so that it now looks like

```
loop
  begin continue:
    if interaction ≠ error_stop_mode then
      return;
    clear_for_error_prompt;
    prompt_input("? ");
    if last = first then
      return;
    c ← buffer[first]
    if c ≥ "a" then
      c ← c + "A" − "a" {convert to uppercase}
    ⟨Interpret code c and return if done⟩;
  end
```

(See [this July 6
commit](https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/commit/5ad82c94428da26bdf64eace0dd3c19e7f09d2a0).
Here I have not lifted ⟨Print the menu…⟩ out of ⟨Interpret code `c`…⟩ as I
did before.)

After studying the original code, I’ve come up with the following alternative
solution. First, we change `error`’s top level (§82) so that

```
if interaction = error_stop_mode then
  ⟨Get the user's advice and return⟩;
```

is

```
while interaction = error_stop_mode do
  ⟨Get the user's advice and return⟩;
```

Then we change §83 to read

```
begin
  clear_for_error_prompt;
  prompt_input("? ");
  if last = first then
    return;
  c ← buffer[first];
  if c ≥ "a" then
    c ← c + "A" − "a"; {convert to uppercase}
  ⟨Interpret code c and return if done⟩;
continue:
end
```

There are also other, more drastic options. We could make the same changes, but
remove the `continue` label from §83 and change ⟨Interpret code `c`…⟩ into
something like

```
if (c ≥ "0") ∧ (c ≤ "9") ∧ deletions_allowed then
  ⟨Delete c − "0" tokens⟩
else
  if (c = "E") ∧ (base_ptr > 0) then
    …
  else
    case c of
      debug "D"
        begin
          debug_help;
        end;
      gubed
      "H":
        ⟨Print the help information⟩;
      "I":
        ⟨Introduce new material from the terminal and return⟩;
      "Q", "R", "S":
        ⟨Change the interaction level and return⟩;
      "X":
        begin
          interaction ← scroll_mode;
          jump_out;
        end;
    othercases
      ⟨Print the menu of available options⟩
    endcases
```

where `goto continue` has been removed from the deletion code, from the
debugging code, and from the help-displaying code. In my opinion, this is worse,
because it’s not as obvious that the menu might be printed even if `c` is `"E"`
or a digit.

Other places besides `error` could be changed as well. We could make
`term_input` or `prompt_input` explicitly validate the assumption that
`selector` ∈ {`term_only`, `term_and_log`}. For example, `prompt_input(#)` might
be made to expand into

```
begin
  if (selector ≠ term_only) ∧ (selector ≠ term_and_log) then
    confusion("selector");
  wake_up_terminal();
  print(#);
  term_input;
end
```

Of course, that would be helpful only if any more bugs of this sort exist in the
program.

---

Addendum: Metafont and TeX share a lot of programming, and in fact their versions of the `error` routine are nearly identical. So it isn’t too surprising that this bug can happen in both programs. It’s not as bad in Metafont, though; no segmentation fault can occur. The problematic first line this time is `\1:=^Ax`, where `^A` is control+`a`. (Any invalid character will do, but it must be typed directly, since Metafont doesn't have an equivalent to TeX's `^^` syntax.) You’ll get the error

```
Improper `:=' will be changed to `='.
```

The rest of the interaction proceeds as before. You type `1`, Metafont decries the invalid character, then you type `q`, and Metafont waits for input after supposedly entering batch mode.

There are of course other ways to cause the bug. You could say `\1;^Ax`, but you’d have to delete two tokens instead of just one.

Most of the exposition above about TeX applies to Metafont, although many of the section numbers are different. The `selector` shenanigans don’t happen, since Metafont expects it to be between 0 and 5 and does nothing if it isn’t.

Comment: The tombstone end-of-proof symbol. Nice!

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce the behavior with `tex` with the following test document

```
\tracingall
\catcode`\^^E=15
\s^^EH
```

If I run `tex test`, I get

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./testinv.tex
{vertical mode: \tracingstats}
{\tracingpages}
{\tracingoutput}
{\tracinglostchars}
{\tracingmacros}
{\tracingparagraphs}
{\tracingrestores}
{\showboxbreadth}
{\showboxdepth}
{\catcode}
{undefined}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \s
      ^^EH
? 1
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.3 \s^^E
         H
? q
OK, entering \batchmode

>
```

The last line denotes the shell prompt to which I only get if I press the return key.

Why is somebody telling that the behavior cannot be reproduced in TL 2020? Good question. Until 2018, LaTeX made several characters invalid, including `^^E`, in order to catch faulty input. The situation changed when UTF-8 was made the default input encoding and now `^^E` is no longer assigned category code 15 in the format.

If I hit `r` instead, I get

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./testinv.tex
{vertical mode: \tracingstats}
{\tracingpages}
{\tracingoutput}
{\tracinglostchars}
{\tracingmacros}
{\tracingparagraphs}
{\tracingrestores}
{\showboxbreadth}
{\showboxdepth}
{\catcode}
{undefined}
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \s
      ^^EH
? 1
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.3 \s^^E
         H
? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
l.3 \s^^EH

?
```

which hints that the invalid character is indeed ignored and the `1` instruction (ignore one token) has not yet been performed and TeX is still waiting for user input.

Moral of the story: an invalid character is, well, invalid and is not taken into account when tokens are being deleted during error recovery.

On the other hand, the

```
? q
OK, entering \batchmode
```

line should mean what it says (but it doesn't, just like when `r` is hit). This might be a genuine bug.

---

A shorter test file is

```
\s^^?H
```

The log file when doing the operations `1` and `q` at the prompt, but hitting return once more is

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex 2020.4.17)  27 JUN 2020 10:34
**test
(./test.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \s
      ^^?H
? 1
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 \s^^?
         H
? q
OK, entering \batchmode...
l.1 \s^^?H
          
? )
! Emergency stop.
<*> test
           
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

No pages of output.
```

Comment: Thank a lot. The answer is really helpful. And do you know why "H" is essential for this segfault? If I delete "H" the segfault will disappear.